# Utility Network analyst - C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, utility-network-analyst

This is related to [Utility Network Analyst tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/112358/utility-network-analyst). I would like to build a button to accomplish the following:

A Utility Network Analyst solve-function for downstream with flagging. Ofcourse, the user will set the flag and select the downstream options. When the “new” button is clicked, it will perform the “Solve” function in the Utility Network Analyst tool plus get the objects' information affected by the downstream.

I am very new to Esri. Can anyone help me?

I am using VS2010 C#.